# Excel Combobox in Python xlwt module

Tags: python, excel, combobox, xlwt, xlrd

Is this possible? Generation of Excel combobox in a cell using xlwt or similar module?

When I load the xls using xlrd, then copy and save it using xlwt, the combobox from original xls is lost.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. xlrd doesn't pick up the combo box and suchlike.